# Instance variable not working in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, model

I am trying to create persistante variable local to my model but although something that sounds so simple is not working.

I have this in my model:

```
    class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base

    @username = "empty"
    @admin = false


  def self.setUser(name, isAdmin)
    @username = name
    @admin = isAdmin        
  end

  def self.get_user (user)#an attempt to access the current_user but did not work i call this from the controller (I understand it is not best practice)
    #@user = user
    self.setUser(user.username,user.admin?)
  end 


  def has_not_occurred
    errors.add("property_of","name is not valid:#{@username}") if !validPropertyOf?

  end

  end
  def validProperty_of?
    return property_of == @username # || @Admin
  end



end
```

I actually get a "" instead of "empty" or the new value of username in set.user. How do I make these values persist? I have printed the values inside each method so they persist inside the method but not beyond for some reason.

@username is always nil or "" when it gets to has_not_accurred.
Why is this and how do I make it persist?  Thank you so much.

I cannont access @user when I set it either (get_user method). I get a nil instance later down at validateProperty_of

Comment: Your question is unclear, just some pieces of code, impossible to understand where these pieces came from. You should put source with model, class scopes, because, i think you have problem with scope visibility, not with persistent.

Comment: I included the relevant parts of the model now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded Rails now it works. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget about database table, you haven't create this one, that's why every variables are non-persistent.

Comment: You mean I haven't created the Coupons table? I do have the table and coupons can be created and delete. I am having trouble validating the property_of attribute through.

Comment: Did you define a migration to add a column?

Comment: indeed. I scaffolded a coupon class with all the proper attributes and I have been using them it for a while. What I ended up doing is setting the attribute at the create method. But that does not give me the proper security I am looking for. Suggestions still appreciated.